# Visual Studio 19 & 22 Error on Teams Explorer "An item with the same key has already been added."

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

for some reason I whenever I go into Team Explorer in visual studios 2019 or 2022, there is an error message on the top bar, no matter what project I open or what I try to do to fix this, this will not go away.

This is what I'm seeing:

[image]

Everywhere I look for a fix, none of the solutions seem to match what I'm seeing.  It's not prject/solution specific, there is no Resources.resx file, a lot of the solutions also appear to be for Visual Studios 2015.

This only occurs when I open the Teams Explorer Tab, in the Changes section.  This has never been an issue until just a few weeks ago and I cannot make it go away.  Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Team-Explorer-Changes-and-Work-Item-Wind/926176?space=8&ftype=problem&preview2=true&q=team+explorer+an+item+with+the+same+key